# Can I use a namespace::user-defined-literals directly in an expression

Tags: c++11, user-defined-literals

Is it possible to write a user defined literal without writing `using namespace xxx;`. Something like `<literal value><namespace>::<UDL>;`
For instance

```
namespace tostr
{
    std::string operator "" _UP(const char *str, unsigned long long int)
    {  //transformation goes here
    }       
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    //using namespace tostr;    
    //std::string upperCase = "hello world.\n"_UP; //OK : Works perfectly.
    //Something like this
    std::string upperCase = "hello world.\n"tostr::_UP;  //????
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use namespaced literal operators without the using declaration according to C++14 standard, §13.5.8 (dunno if this exists in C++11).

If you want to limit the effect of the using declaration (eg. if you want to use the literals with same names from different namespaces), you should use `{}` scopes for that.

Comment: Tank you @f1u77y